# JSON error in swift

Tags: json, xcode, swift

I am new to Swift and API programming and am running into the following error:

> uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[__NSCFNumber length]

This is the line that is causing this error:

`print(json[“totalPostsByUser”])`

For more context, this is a more complete code sample:

```
let jsonStr = NSString(data: request.HTTPBody!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
   let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse
   var err: NSError?

   if httpResponse!.statusCode == 201 {
      if error == nil {
         let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
         let jsonData: NSData = jsonStr!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
         do {
            if let json: AnyObject = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) {
               let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding:  NSUTF8StringEncoding)
               print(responseString)
               print(json["totalPostsByUser"])
               totalPostsByUser = (json["totalPostsByUser"] as? Int)!
            }
         } catch let parseError {
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: `totalPostsByUser = (json["totalPostsByUser"] as? Int)!` should either be `totalPostsByUser = json["totalPostsByUser"] as! Int` or `totalPostsByUser = json["totalPostsByUser"] as? Int` (hint, the second option is better)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to replace some piece of code with below code,

```
if let json: NSMutableDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as? NSMutableDictionary
    {
               let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding:  NSUTF8StringEncoding)
               print(responseString)
               //print(json["totalPostsByUser"])
               print(json.valueForKey("totalPostsByUser"))
               //totalPostsByUser = (json["totalPostsByUser"] as? Int)!
    }
```

Convert anyObject to MutableDictionary which will be easy to extract value from key.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: You are welcome :) and please accept this answer so it will be helpful to others also